# Can I make my FlatList items draggable in React Native without using any external package or library?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, web, react-native-flatlist

I am making a list of items using FlatList in react native. Now I want to make the items of the FlatList draggable.

I only want to use FlatList but online solutions are showing me to use draggable FlatList

Comment: Hey, I'm in the same situation, have you found any solution?